# What is the NextJS + NodeJS authorization principle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, next.js

I kind of did authorization, but it doesn't work well, because sometimes it doesn't update the token and it just ends. Also my solution is not safe. I could not find a suitable option on the Internet.

Objective: We need to check the user's role in order to close access to part of the functionality and pages. It is important to send requests from both client (React) and Server side rendering (NextJS) with header authorization 'Bearer $ {accessToken}'. Also every day the accessToken expires and I refresh it with refreshToken.

How I did it:
On each page where authorization is required, I registered getServerSideProps, in which I request an accessToken from the cookie and if it is not there I try to request a new one using refreshToken (which again lies in the cookie), if it is not there then return 404 page. If I have successfully received the accessToken, I pass it to the header authorization 'Bearer $ {accessToken}'. And thus, already on the server, through the middleware, I check the role and the token, if everything is ok, I give an answer.

I tried to get accessToken client side (React), but then I cannot make an authorized request in getServerSideProps.

Perhaps I forgot to describe something. I would be grateful if you can suggest a more correct solution. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the code where you're having the issue?

Comment: @juliomalves What kind of code? I have this general logic of the entire application

Comment: Can you clarify this part: "I tried to get accessToken client side (React), but then I cannot make an authorized request in getServerSideProps"?

Comment: @juliomalves I need to send a request when loading a page to getserversideprops. But for this I need to get an accessToken, since then I specify it in the Authorization 'Bearer $ {accessToke}'. I can't generate a token in React as getServerSideProps fires first.

Comment: @juliomalves Main question where to store accessToken so i can access it from server side nextjs and from the "react" side to further send requests to node js